# Accessing a private repository from a docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image using a dockerfile

the problem is when the instruction `apt-get update` get executed I get this error

```
Err:8 https://artifactory-name bionic-updates Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: artifactory-ip]
```

So I want to know if the docker container reuse the certificates configured in my host machine

or there is a configuration i must add in order to access the artifactory from my container.

Ps: my host machine is ubuntu and I have no problem accessing the artifactory

Comment: Docker does not re-use certificates from your host. If you need to install an additional certificate authority in order to validate that certificate, you would need to install the CA certificate into your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ca-certificates before: `sudo apt install ca-certificates` or if you want to bypass the security  add `[trusted=yes]` in the `sources.list`

Comment: do you mean to add this "sudo apt install ca-certificates" in the docker file

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common that docker base images have root CA certificates that are out of date. (root CA certs are the ones that browsers and operating systems have built-in so they are always trusted, those certs still change but are usually updated automatically).

So it's common to start a Dockerfile with commands needed to bring those certs up to date. Here are two commands for Debian based images:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       apt-transport-https

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       ca-certificates \
```

The first ensures that `apt` can read SSL/TLS sources. The second updates those root CA certs.

Comment: problem is the command fails at the first ```apt-get update``` cause the repos it is trying to updates the list throw that certificate issue